# json_encode not working with urldecode

Tags: php, json, decode, urldecode

json_encode not working with urldecode. Please give some solution

```
<?php
$decode_str = array();
$str = "%ED%A0%BD%ED%BA%97%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF+89%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%86+%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF.+%D8%AA%DA%A9+%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B2%ED%A0%BD%ED%BA%97";

$decode_str['output'] = urldecode($str);
echo json_encode($decode_str);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add `echo json_last_error_msg();` to the end of it, you will see that there is a json error.

```
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

The string you are trying to encode has malformed UTF-8 Characters. You will need to fix the characted encoding before you can encode it into json.

Answer (score 1):

Use **utf8_decode**() as well.

```
$decode_str = array();

$str = "%ED%A0%BD%ED%BA%97%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF+89%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%86+%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF.+%D8%AA%DA%A9+%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B2%ED%A0%BD%ED%BA%97";

$decode_str['output'] = utf8_decode(urldecode($str));

echo json_encode($decode_str);
```